# Resquesting PHP from JavaScript returns content of php

Tags: javascript, php

I want to request a php-File from a JavaScript file. But instead of returning the value of echo it returns the content of php for some reason.

Here is my JS-File:

```
function request(fullURL) {
    const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("GET", fullURL, false);
    http.send();
    return (http.status === 200) ? http.responseText : null;
}

let data = request("scripts/php/test.php");
console.log(data);
```

Here is the PHP-File:

```
<?php
$x = "content data";
echo $x;
```

And here is the output:

```
<?php
$x = "content data";
echo $x;
```

As you can see the output and the PHP-File are the same. Why is this the case?

I tried to implement the ability to read a file from php. It wont work.

Comment: `Why is this the case`...because whatever webserver you're running this on is not configured to execute PHP code.

Comment: @ADyson Im running it via XAMPP. And it surely supports PHP because it worked in the past. Where can I enable it?

Comment: So...you definitely opened the HTML page which invokes the JS code by going to your browser and typing in something like `http://localhost/yourpage.html` ? (You didn't, for example, run it directly from the disk, or via an IDE like Visual Studio Code? Because those approaches won't involve the Apache server which comes with XAMPP)

Comment: I tried it with my IDE (IntelliJ) which won't worked and also with XAMPP which won't work either.

Comment: what do you see in the address bar in your browser when calling this code?

Comment: When launching with XAMPP: http://localhost:63342/testproj/test.html
When launching with IntelliJ: http://localhost:63342/testproj/test.html?_ijt=cg38v3hhum7t62r4qtdmndtrk4&_ij_reload=RELOAD_ON_SAVE

Comment: XAMPP's Apache install doesn't normally run on that port - did you change the configuration, specifically?

Comment: you are right. I tryped in the wrong port. With the XAMPP-Port (80) it works. Is there any fix for IntelliJ because it seems to be an IntelliJ issue?

Comment: I don't know IntelliJ at all, but I'd assume you can change a setting somewhere to make it use a different webserver than its (presumably) built-in one. You'd have to check the docs, or do some research